# Unity Transparent Background Shows As Black

Tags: unity-game-engine, png, transparency

[image: My settings]

The png in my game's transparent background shows up as black in unity, anyone know what to do?

I expected it to be a tranparent background but it's not so any help is appreciated.

Comment: A *.png* isn't transparent "automagically", it needs a transparency layer on an alpha channel. If it doesn't have that, it won't be transparent. Also, converting a *.bmp*, *.jpg* or anything else not having transparency on its A-channel, to *.png* doesn't make it transparent unless you added the transparency manually.

Comment: @TheNomad I think it does have an alpha channel and it hasn’t been converted but I’ll check

Comment: So far, I haven't had any issues with Unity interpreting alpha channels. Make sure it's not black, though.

Comment: @TheNomad The background is definitely transparent using alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was putting it in the sprite renderer which doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean? A transparent sprite can be drawn using a Sprite Renderer.